# Dynamically created divs aren't clickable C# ASP.NET

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

Basically I'm creating divs on basis of a number. Here is where i'm creating these divs:

```
cssStyle.Attributes["href"]="Content/Options/"+(Global.NumberOfResponses).ToString() +".css";
string x = "<table class=\"Centralizetable\"><tr>";
for (int i = 0; i < Global.NumberOfResponses; i++) { 
    if(i==0){
        x = x + "<td><div class=\"leftmost\" onClick=\"myClickListener\" runat=\"server\"><img class=\"imageProps\" src=\"/Images/1.jpg\" id=\"imgChoice_" + i.ToString()+ "\" /><p class=\"optionText\">Good</p></div></td>";
    }
    else {
        x = x + "<td><div class=\"center\"  onClick=\"myClickListener\" runat=\"server\"><img class=\"imageProps\" src=\"/Images/1.jpg\" id=\"imgChoice_" + i.ToString() + "\" /><p class=\"optionText\">Good</p></div></td>";
    }
}

x = x + "</tr></table>";

multichoice.InnerHtml = x;
```

And it is supposed to call this function:

```
public void myClickListener(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Image A = sender as Image;
    ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "alert", "alert('"+A.ID+"')", true);
}
```

But the dynamically created divs aren't clickable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at the rendered HTML, you should see the [runat="Server"] attribute is being rendered.  You are creating dynamic HTML, but its not processed as a server side control.

You can change the click event to call a JavaScript function or change they way you are creating the elements if you need to invoke a server call

see MSDN for [how to programmatically adding controls](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kyt0fzt1.aspx)

Comment: Thank you! Let me leave this here for others,
This is how i achieved it:
`x = x + "<td><div class=\"leftmost\"><img class=\"imageProps\" src=\"/Images/1.jpg\"  onClick=\"tempFunc(this)\" runat=\"server\" id=\"imgChoice_" + i.ToString() + "\" /><p class=\"optionText\">Good</p></div></td>";`
     `               
      function tempFunc(img) {
         alert($(img).attr('src'));
        }
`

Answer (score 0):

You should try `OnServerClick` instead of `onClick`:

```
cssStyle.Attributes["href"]="Content/Options/"+(Global.NumberOfResponses).ToString() +".css";
string x = "<table class=\"Centralizetable\"><tr>";
for (int i = 0; i < Global.NumberOfResponses; i++) { 
    if(i==0){
        x = x + "<td><div class=\"leftmost\" OnServerClick=\"myClickListener\" runat=\"server\"><img class=\"imageProps\" src=\"/Images/1.jpg\" id=\"imgChoice_" + i.ToString()+ "\" /><p class=\"optionText\">Good</p></div></td>";
    }
    else {
        x = x + "<td><div class=\"center\"  OnServerClick=\"myClickListener\" runat=\"server\"><img class=\"imageProps\" src=\"/Images/1.jpg\" id=\"imgChoice_" + i.ToString() + "\" /><p class=\"optionText\">Good</p></div></td>";
    }
}

x = x + "</tr></table>";

multichoice.InnerHtml = x;
```

See [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.htmlcontrols.htmlbutton.onserverclick(v=vs.110).aspx) and [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3167246/asp-net-html-html-buttons-onclick-property-inside-asp-net-cs) for more